# Get expanded path from webpack alias

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Is there a good way to take the webpack alias from the webpack config:

```
config.resolve.alias = {
  NormalizeNodePath: (__dirname, 'node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css'),
  BluePrintIconsNodePath: (__dirname, 'node_modules/@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css'),
  BluePrintCoreNodePath: (__dirname, 'node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css')
}
```

And expose it as a string in javascript?

Comment: So you want to take the `join(__dirname, "...")` string, use it as an alias _and_ in your codebase? Just so I understand correctly

Comment: I just want to find some way to save that string, and be able to use it in the codebase, if there is a better way of doing this in webpack I'd love to do know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, there are a few ways you can accomplish this.

1. Define a variable for these strings, then import them in your code and in the webpack config

```
// paths.js
const NormalizeNodePath = join(__dirname, 'node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css')

module.exports = {
  NormalizeNodePath,
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js
const { NormalizeNodePath } = require('./paths')

// use it in alias config
```

```
// src/whatever.js
const { NormalizeNodePath } = require('../paths')
// use in your code
```

2. Use the [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) and expose it as a constant in your code, which will be replaced with a literal string during bundling.

```
const NormalizeNodePath = join(__dirname, 'node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css')

module.exports = {
  // other config...

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      NormalizeNodePath
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      NormalizeNodePath,
    })
  ]
}

// Use the variable name `NormalizeNodePath` in your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to inject global variables into your code.

**Example**

```
const alias = {
  NormalizeNodePath: (__dirname, "node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css"),
  BluePrintIconsNodePath: (__dirname, "node_modules/@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css"),
  BluePrintCoreNodePath: (__dirname, "node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css")
};

const config = {
  resolve: {
    alias
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin(alias)]
};
```